# How to add swagger.json at root of service package?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have configured my project with swagger but when i try to access the http://10.10.10.198:8083:8083/PatientApp/services it gives me error that "Can't read swagger JSON from http://10.10.10.198:8083/PatientApp/services" how can i add swagger json in project?

Comment: Trying adding swagger.json to the end of your URL

Comment: Can't read swagger JSON from http://10.10.10.198:8083/PatientApp/services/swagger.json

Comment: What URL are you using in the index.html ?